# Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, Example 5 Sec 4-4

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand the following example about geodesics of a surface of revolution.
[image]

First fundamental form along the meridian $u=$constant and $v=v(s)$ would be $f^2(v)+g^2(v)$ computing $ \langle  \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x} \rangle_p$, right? I can't relate that to $(f')^2+(g')^2)(v')^2=1$, been stuck on this for days, and It might be trivial but really don't see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, he’s saying the curve is arclength parametrized: The velocity vector has length $1$.

Comment: The velocity vector along $v=v(s)$, $u$ constant is $\mathbf{x}'(s)=(f'(v(s))\cos u, f'(v(s))\sin u,g'(v(s)))v'(s)$ and so the first fundamental form gives $1=\langle\mathbf{x}'(s),\mathbf{x}'(s)\rangle=(f'^2+g'^2)v'^2$.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad, thank you very much both!!